# automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession crashes the app on simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, avcapturesession

After setting this value to YES of `AVCaptureSession` object, my app crashes. It I run the same code on the device it works fine, but when I start it on the iPhone 5 simulator with iOS 10 installed it crashes every time.

Comment: I see the same thing on iOS 10 only. No crashing on lower OS versions